# What is the recommended way to create SharePoint Internet site in SP 2019?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

Our requirement is to have an internet public CMS website for our organization with some information such as news(will be updated by our team), contact us(where anyone can submit anonymously).

So, We are implementing a new SP 2019 on-prem public internet site and our SP 2019 server arch is 1 App, 1 FE, and 1 SQL. The external team that is implementing SP, they are creating 2 web applications SPWebAPP1 and SPWebAPP2. They are claiming that they create SPWebAPP2 web application to have a custom master page design and use AJAX to fetch list information from SPWebAPP1, so that site loading will be fast. Is that advisable to have a separate web application for API? But we wanted to have a single web app as SPWebApp1 by extending it to the Internet zone without using SPWebApp2 since we don’t have any other application integration. What is recommendable?

To keep my question simple, What is Microsoft recommended way to create an internet SharePoint 2019 site with some custom master page design?

Comment: There is so many factors to take into consideration here espically around anonymous sites and protecting the administration pages (View forms lockdown etc). But the concept and justification of having two web applications one for api one for presentation does not make sense. ultimately the ajax call will come from the clients browser, so it will require access authentication to both web apps. why not just have the single app? Its late and I will relook at the question in the morning. Any further details you can provide would be good.

Comment: Hi James, Thanks for your response. Could you please let me know what more details you needed? Since the external party is implementing this SP 2019 for us, I'll get more details from them as per your question.